# Срабатывание функции с обработчиком 1 раз

Tags: javascript

Функция задаёт переворот карты на 180 градусов. Задача в том чтобы при клике по одной из карт она переворачивалась и при клике на следующую уже ничего не происходило.

```js
function turnCard() {

const card = document.getElementsByClassName('wrap');

    for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        card[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
            if (this.className === 'wrap easy') {
                this.classList.add('rotated')
            }
        })
    }
}
turnCard()
```

ещё попробовал как то так

```js
let number = 0;

function rotate() {

    if (this.className === 'wrap easy') {
        this.classList.add('rotated')
        number++
        console.log(number)
    }
}

function turnCard() {
    for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        if (number === 0) {
            card[i].addEventListener('click', rotate)
        } else if (number > 0) {
            card[i].removeEventListener('click', rotate)
        }
    }
}
turnCard()
```

Comment: у вас два варианта: 1) отцепить обработчик события после первого клика 2) добавить флаг первого клика. Для первого вам придется поименовать функцию обработчика, для второго и сделать замыкание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var rotadet = false;  // флаг "не перевернуто"

function turnCard() {
    const card = document.getElementsByClassName('wrap');

    for (i = 0; i < card.length; i++) {
        card[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
            if (!rotadet) {  // если "не перевернуто"
                this.classList.add('rotated'); 
                rotadet = true;  // отмечаем "перевернуто" и клик больше не сработает
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: На всякий случай, отправляю наглядный пример https://jsfiddle.net/tpx7c34n/

Answer (score 0):

Можно добавить класс к элементу, затем сделать выборку
Если есть перевернутые карты - то ничего не делать.

Забегая вперед, что бы была перевернута максимум одна карта, в обработчике сначала сбрасывается класс переворота для всех, затем добавляется на нужный.

На нативном js писать ломает. Лаконичный пример с jquery:

```js
$('.card').click ( function() {
  if ( $('.card.rotated').length ) return;
  $( this ).addClass('rotated');
}
);

/** Вариант-2 - активна только одна карта -
$('.card').click ( function() {
  $( '.card' ).removeClass('rotated');
  $( this ).addClass('rotated');
}
);
*/
```

```css
.card {
background: silver;
margin: 1em;
padding: 1em;
display: inline-block;
}

.card.rotated {
 background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">1</div>
<div class="card">2</div>
<div class="card">3</div>
<div class="card">4</div>
```